# Creating my own dll and scripting language to use with my MFC application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am currently new to MFC in terms of creating my own dll and then create a scripting language  in order to use this dll with my application. Could you guys kindly suggest me any possible links and directions as to from where should I start and go about learning about dll's and my own scripting language and execute them in my application?

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what language you want to use as scripting language. You can embed Visual Basic and Javascript through the Windows Scripting Host as a COM object, you can embed Python using the raw Python embedding API or Boost.Python, you can embed other languages like PHP and Ruby using their native embedding API's, you can use specific embedding languages like Lua. Learn about dll's from MSDN, start e.g. reading from the docs of the LoadLibrary function, it will lead you to technical notes from there.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Could you suggest me as to which of these are more recent and would tend to get used much more in the future?

Comment: Well I didn't want to do so because it's flamefest area, but let me put it like this: Python is very popular to embed because it's easy to do so (esp. with Boost.Python) and has a fairly good reputation (i.e., is known to be easy to use yet not in such wide use as to be unfashionable). Lua is designed for embedding and is used in many high-profile applications (e.g. World of Warcraft). WSH is old stuff, wouldn't suggest it. PHP is my personal choice but that's because I know PHP very well and its internals reasonably well. So I would look at Python and Lua and check which one you like best.

Comment: I am going ahead with Python and hopefully it should be alright :). Thanks for your suggestions.